# Trouble hosting ASP.NET + Entity Framework website on Plesk

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, plesk

I have made a simple database in SQL Server using SSMS with a single table and inserted only one record. Next, I have created a simple webpage (Default.aspx) with only one GridView control. In the Page_Load() method, I have simply used entity framework to populate the gridview with the following code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EMCLabCustomerDataEntities context = new EMCLabCustomerDataEntities();
    GridView1.DataSource = context.Users.ToList();
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

This code works great locally. The following is the web.config page that I have locally.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".edmx" type="System.Data.Entity.Design.AspNet.EntityDesignerBuildProvider" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EMCLabCustomerDataEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Code.CRMSample.csdl|res://*/App_Code.CRMSample.ssdl|res://*/App_Code.CRMSample.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=CARRIZO;initial catalog=EMCLabCustomerData;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v12.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

I have changed the connection string after I have uploaded the files in the server. This is the connection string that I am getting in the myLittleAdmin for SQL server 2005.

```
Data Source=208.91.198.174;Network Library=;Connection Timeout=15;Packet Size=4096;Integrated Security=no;User ID=admin_emc;Encrypt=no;
```

Now, when I load the page, I am getting this error.

> Configuration Error    Description: An error occurred during the
>   processing of a configuration file required to service this request.
>   Please review the specific error details below and modify your
>   configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: An error occurred creating the configuration
>   section handler for entityFramework: Could not load file or assembly
>   'EntityFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> Source Error:
>
> An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error
>   settings for this application prevent the details of the application
>   error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could,
>   however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
>
> Source File:  D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\labemc.org\httpdocs\web.config
>   Line:  9
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' could not be loaded.
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Comment: You have reference to EF 4 but in your web.config it's setup to use EF 5. Check if all your projects have the same version of EF. Also check in your bin folder and try deleting and compiling again

Comment: Well, I only got the option of using EF 5 or 6.x. How do I reference to EF 4?

Comment: I think the oldest EF you can get is 4.1.1 have a look here https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/

Comment: Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 4.1.10311 .

Comment: Will that have any effect on the code that I am accustomed with? I checked the NuGet site for the information. How does this downgrade effect me?

Also, does the connection string look good?

Comment: Hey one thing if you are already using EF 5. How the hell did you get an error for EF version 4? Seems like you have some reference's in the bin folder hidden. Try deleting all reference from your project in bin directory then rebuild and deploy it to your server

Comment: Okay. Sounds good to me.